# Unexpected draw order with hidden surface removal enabled

Tags: webgl

I'm trying to learn WebGL and I've run into a small problem relating to hidden surface removal.

In this snippet, I've got two triangles drawn, the view position can be changed by using the arrow keys.  When moving around the scene, sometimes the 'back' triangle will be drawn in front of the 'front' triangle, even though `DEPTH_TEST` is enabled.

I have no idea why this is happening. There doesn't seem to be any major differences in the `ViewMatrix` when the triangles swap.

```js
class Matrix4 {
  constructor (elements) {
    this._elements = elements || [
      1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
      0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
    ]
  }

  elements (order) {
    if (order === Matrix4.COLUMN_MAJOR) {
      let e = this._elements
      return [
        e[0], e[4], e[8], e[12],
        e[1], e[5], e[9], e[13],
        e[2], e[6], e[10], e[14],
        e[3], e[7], e[11], e[15]
      ]
    }

    return this._elements
  }
}

Matrix4.ROW_MAJOR = 1000
Matrix4.COLUMN_MAJOR = 1001

class Vector3D {
  constructor (...args) {
    if (args.length === 3) {
      this.x = args[0]
      this.y = args[1]
      this.z = args[2]
    } else if (args[0] instanceof Array) {
      let arr = args[0]
      this.x = arr[0]
      this.y = arr[1]
      this.z = arr[2]
    }
  }

  add () {
    return new Vector(
      this.x + v.x,
      this.y + v.y,
      this.z + v.z
    )
  }

  divide (n) {
    if (n === 0) return new Vector3D([0, 0, 0])
    return new Vector3D(
      this.x / n,
      this.y / n,
      this.z / n
    )
  }

  multiply (n) {
    return new Vector3D(
      this.x * n,
      this.y * n,
      this.z * n
    )
  }

  subtract (v) {
    return new Vector3D(
      this.x - v.x,
      this.y - v.y,
      this.z - v.z
    )
  }

  cross (v) {
    return new Vector3D(
      this.y * v.z - this.z * v.y,
      this.z * v.x - this.x * v.z,
      this.x * v.y - this.y * v.x
    )
  }

  length () {
    return Math.sqrt(
      Math.pow(this.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.y, 2) + Math.pow(this.z, 2)
    )
  }

  normal () {
    return this.divide(this.length())
  }
}

function lookAt (camera, target, up) {
  let dir = target.subtract(camera).normal().multiply(-1)
  let x = up.cross(dir).normal()
  let y = dir.cross(x).normal()
  return new Matrix4([
    x.x, y.x, dir.x, camera.x,
    x.y, y.y, dir.y, camera.y,
    x.z, y.z, dir.z, camera.z,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
  ])
}

function perspective (fov, width, height, near, far) {
  fov *= Math.PI / 180
  const ar = width / height
  const mat = new Matrix4()
  mat._elements[0] = 1 / ar * Math.tan(fov / 2)
  mat._elements[5] = 1 / Math.tan(fov / 2)
  mat._elements[10] = (-near - far) / (near - far)
  mat._elements[11] = 2 * far * near / (near - far)
  mat._elements[14] = -1
  mat._elements[15] = 0
  return mat
}

(function () {
  const gl = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('webgl')

  setCanvas(gl)

  // Specify the colour for clearing the canvas
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

  // Actually clear the canvas
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
  
  initShaders(
    gl,
    document.getElementById('vertex-shader').text,
    document.getElementById('fragment-shader').text
  )

  const vertices = new Float32Array([
     -0.5, -0.5, -0.4,   1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      0.5, -0.5, -0.4,   0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
      0.0, 0.5, -0.4,   0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
     0.0,  -0.6, 0.4,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.5, 0.5, 0.4,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     -0.5, 0.5, 0.4,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0
  ])
  const vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer()
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer)
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
  
  const FSIZE = vertices.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT

  const a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position')
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, FSIZE * 6, 0)
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position)

  const a_Color = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Color')
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Color, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, FSIZE * 6, FSIZE * 3)
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Color)
  
  const projMatrix = perspective(30, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 0.1, 1000.0)
  // const projMatrix = new Matrix4()
  const u_ProjMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_ProjMatrix')
  const projMatrixElements = new Float32Array(projMatrix.elements(Matrix4.COLUMN_MAJOR))
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_ProjMatrix, false, projMatrixElements)
  
  const cameraPosition = new Vector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.1)
  const targetPosition = new Vector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
  const up = new Vector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
  const viewMatrix = lookAt(cameraPosition, targetPosition, up)

  // WebGL matrices are in column major order
  const viewMatrixElements = new Float32Array(viewMatrix.elements(Matrix4.COLUMN_MAJOR))
  const u_ViewMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_ViewMatrix')
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_ViewMatrix, false, viewMatrixElements)

  document.onkeydown = function (ev) {
    if (ev.key === 'ArrowRight') {
      cameraPosition.x += 0.01
    } else if (ev.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
      cameraPosition.x -= 0.01
    } else if (ev.key === 'ArrowUp') {
      cameraPosition.y -= 0.01
    } else if (ev.key === 'ArrowDown') {
      cameraPosition.y += 0.01
    }
    const viewMatrix = lookAt(cameraPosition, targetPosition, up)
    const viewMatrixElements = new Float32Array(viewMatrix.elements(Matrix4.COLUMN_MAJOR))
    const u_ViewMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_ViewMatrix')
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_ViewMatrix, false, viewMatrixElements)
    draw(gl)
  }

  draw(gl)

  function draw (gl) {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6)
  }

  function initShaders (gl, vert, frag) {
    const program = createProgram(gl, vert, frag)

    gl.useProgram(program)
    gl.program = program

    return true
  }

  function createProgram (gl, vert, frag) {
    const vertexShader = loadShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vert)
    const fragmentShader = loadShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag)

    const program = gl.createProgram()

    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader)
    gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader)

    gl.linkProgram(program)
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
      throw new Error('Could not link shader program')
    }

    return program
  }

  function loadShader (gl, t, src) {
    const shader = gl.createShader(t)
    gl.shaderSource(shader, src)
    gl.compileShader(shader)
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      throw new Error(`${t === 35633 ? 'Vertex' : 'Fragment'} shader did not compile`)
    }
    return shader
  }
  
  function setCanvas (gl) {
    const canvas = gl.canvas
    canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth
    canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)
  }
})()
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/vertex-shader">
  attribute vec4 a_Position;
  attribute vec4 a_Color;
  uniform mat4 u_ViewMatrix;
  varying vec4 v_Color;
  void main () {
    gl_Position = u_ViewMatrix * a_Position;
    v_Color = a_Color;
  }
</script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/fragment-shader">
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec4 v_Color;
  void main () {
    gl_FragColor = v_Color;
  }
</script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Here's what I mean:

[image]

[image]

The two triangles suddenly swap, then swap back again.

What is happening here?

Comment: Typo: the line `x.z, y.z, dir.x, camera.z,` should have `dir.z` instead of `dir.x`

Comment: Simple as that. Works great now

Comment: your lookAt is still wrong even if that worked it's working by luck. Try it. Setup the projection matrix, put something somewhere, put the camera somewhere else, use your lookAt to generate a view matrix to "look at" that thing and watch it fail

Comment: @gman you're right. I cannot get it to work with a projection matrix. What is wrong with the lookAt function? I can't tell.

Comment: Like I said in my answer. A view matrix has to be a matrix that effectively makes the origin of the space be the camera's position. I updated the answer to include perspective. I also changed that function. I don't know what's wrong with yours and I don't have time to figure it out. I just know putting different ones in works.

Answer (score 0):

the lookAt function is wrong

It's not clear which kind of lookAt you wanted. Do you want to make objects `lookAt` other objects or do you want to make a view matrix. I prefer the first since it's infinitely more useful than the second but gluLookAt and glm:lookAt do the second.

Given your code directly assigns `viewMatrix` the results of `lookAt` it looks like you want a view matrix. A view matrix moves the space so the camera is at the origin so a simple glance at the code makes it clear that's impossible given the current code

```
function lookAt (camera, target, up) {
  let dir = target.subtract(camera).normal().multiply(-1)
  let x = up.cross(dir).normal()
  let y = dir.cross(x).normal()
  return new Matrix4([
    x.x, y.x, dir.x, camera.x,
    x.y, y.y, dir.y, camera.y,
    x.z, y.z, dir.x, camera.z,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
  ])
```

Since to move the space so camera position is at 0 you'd need to move -cameraPosition assuming everything else was the identity then copying camera directly in the translation column is clearly wrong.

@whydoubt also pointed out you have `dir.x` instead of `dir.z` in the 3rd row.

Here's a new version of lookAt

```
    function lookAt (camera, target, up) {
      let dir = target.subtract(camera).normal().multiply(-1)
      let x = up.cross(dir).normal()
      let y = dir.cross(x).normal()
      return new Matrix4([
        x.x, y.x, dir.x, -x.dot(camera),
        x.y, y.y, dir.y, -y.dot(camera),
        x.z, y.z, dir.z, -dir.dot(camera),
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
      ])
    }
```

Also your `perspective` function I changed to this

```
function perspective(fov, width, height, near, far) {
  const f = Math.tan(Math.PI * 0.5 - 0.5 * fov * Math.PI / 180);
  const rangeInv = 1.0 / (near - far);
  const aspect = width / height;

  return new Matrix4([
    f / aspect, 0, 0, 0,
    0, f, 0, 0,
    0, 
    0, 
    (near + far) * rangeInv, 
    near * far * rangeInv * 2,
    0, 0, -1, 0,
  ]);
}
```

I also changed the colors so one triangle is red-orange and the other blue-green. It's important to be able to tell you're looking in the correct direction. The camera is at Z = 2 looking at Z = 0. The blue-green triangle is at Z = 0.4 and the red-orange triangle is at Z = -0.4 so blue-green should be in front of red-orange

```js
class Matrix4 {
  constructor (elements) {
    this._elements = elements || [
      1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
      0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
    ]
  }

  elements (order) {
    if (order === Matrix4.COLUMN_MAJOR) {
      let e = this._elements
      return [
        e[0], e[4], e[8], e[12],
        e[1], e[5], e[9], e[13],
        e[2], e[6], e[10], e[14],
        e[3], e[7], e[11], e[15]
      ]
    }

    return this._elements
  }
}

Matrix4.ROW_MAJOR = 1000
Matrix4.COLUMN_MAJOR = 1001

class Vector3D {
  constructor (...args) {
    if (args.length === 3) {
      this.x = args[0]
      this.y = args[1]
      this.z = args[2]
    } else if (args[0] instanceof Array) {
      let arr = args[0]
      this.x = arr[0]
      this.y = arr[1]
      this.z = arr[2]
    }
  }

  add () {
    return new Vector(
      this.x + v.x,
      this.y + v.y,
      this.z + v.z
    )
  }

  divide (n) {
    if (n === 0) return new Vector3D([0, 0, 0])
    return new Vector3D(
      this.x / n,
      this.y / n,
      this.z / n
    )
  }

  multiply (n) {
    return new Vector3D(
      this.x * n,
      this.y * n,
      this.z * n
    )
  }

  subtract (v) {
    return new Vector3D(
      this.x - v.x,
      this.y - v.y,
      this.z - v.z
    )
  }

  cross (v) {
    return new Vector3D(
      this.y * v.z - this.z * v.y,
      this.z * v.x - this.x * v.z,
      this.x * v.y - this.y * v.x
    )
  }
  
  dot (v) {
    return this.x * v.x + this.y * v.y + this.z * v.z;
  }

  length () {
    return Math.sqrt(
      Math.pow(this.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.y, 2) + Math.pow(this.z, 2)
    )
  }

  normal () {
    return this.divide(this.length())
  }
}

function lookAt (camera, target, up) {
  let dir = target.subtract(camera).normal().multiply(-1)
  let x = up.cross(dir).normal()
  let y = dir.cross(x).normal()
  return new Matrix4([
    x.x, y.x, dir.x, -x.dot(camera),
    x.y, y.y, dir.y, -y.dot(camera),
    x.z, y.z, dir.z, -dir.dot(camera),
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
  ])
}

function perspective(fov, width, height, near, far) {
  const f = Math.tan(Math.PI * 0.5 - 0.5 * fov * Math.PI / 180);
  const rangeInv = 1.0 / (near - far);
  const aspect = width / height;

  return new Matrix4([
    f / aspect, 0, 0, 0,
    0, f, 0, 0,
    0, 
    0, 
    (near + far) * rangeInv, 
    near * far * rangeInv * 2,
    0, 0, -1, 0,
  ]);
}


(function () {
  const gl = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('webgl')

  setCanvas(gl)

  // Specify the colour for clearing the canvas
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

  // Actually clear the canvas
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
  
  initShaders(
    gl,
    document.getElementById('vertex-shader').text,
    document.getElementById('fragment-shader').text
  )

  const vertices = new Float32Array([
     -0.5, -0.5, -0.4,   1.0, 0.4, 0.0,
      0.5, -0.5, -0.4,   1.0, 0.6, 0.0,
      0.0,  0.5, -0.4,   1.0, 0.8, 0.0,
      0.0, -0.6,  0.4,   0.0, 0.4, 1.0,
      0.5,  0.5,  0.4,   0.0, 0.6, 1.0,
     -0.5,  0.5,  0.4,   0.0, 0.8, 1.0
  ])
  const vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer()
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer)
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW)
  
  const FSIZE = vertices.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT

  const a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position')
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, FSIZE * 6, 0)
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position)

  const a_Color = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Color')
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Color, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, FSIZE * 6, FSIZE * 3)
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Color)
  
  const projMatrix = perspective(30, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 0.1, 1000.0)
  // const projMatrix = new Matrix4()
  const u_ProjMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_ProjMatrix')
  const projMatrixElements = new Float32Array(projMatrix.elements(Matrix4.COLUMN_MAJOR))
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_ProjMatrix, false, projMatrixElements)
  
  const cameraPosition = new Vector3D(0.0, 0.0, 2.0)
  const targetPosition = new Vector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
  const up = new Vector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
  const viewMatrix = lookAt(cameraPosition, targetPosition, up)

  // WebGL matrices are in column major order
  const viewMatrixElements = new Float32Array(viewMatrix.elements(Matrix4.COLUMN_MAJOR))
  const u_ViewMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_ViewMatrix')
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_ViewMatrix, false, viewMatrixElements)

  document.onkeydown = function (ev) {
    if (ev.key === 'ArrowRight') {
      cameraPosition.x += 0.01
    } else if (ev.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
      cameraPosition.x -= 0.01
    } else if (ev.key === 'ArrowUp') {
      cameraPosition.y -= 0.01
    } else if (ev.key === 'ArrowDown') {
      cameraPosition.y += 0.01
    }
    const viewMatrix = lookAt(cameraPosition, targetPosition, up)
    const viewMatrixElements = new Float32Array(viewMatrix.elements(Matrix4.COLUMN_MAJOR))
    const u_ViewMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_ViewMatrix')
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_ViewMatrix, false, viewMatrixElements)
    draw(gl)
  }

  draw(gl)

  function draw (gl) {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6)
  }

  function initShaders (gl, vert, frag) {
    const program = createProgram(gl, vert, frag)

    gl.useProgram(program)
    gl.program = program

    return true
  }

  function createProgram (gl, vert, frag) {
    const vertexShader = loadShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vert)
    const fragmentShader = loadShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag)

    const program = gl.createProgram()

    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader)
    gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader)

    gl.linkProgram(program)
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
      throw new Error('Could not link shader program')
    }

    return program
  }

  function loadShader (gl, t, src) {
    const shader = gl.createShader(t)
    gl.shaderSource(shader, src)
    gl.compileShader(shader)
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      throw new Error(`${t === 35633 ? 'Vertex' : 'Fragment'} shader did not compile`)
    }
    return shader
  }
  
  function setCanvas (gl) {
    const canvas = gl.canvas
    canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth
    canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)
  }
})()
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/vertex-shader">
  attribute vec4 a_Position;
  attribute vec4 a_Color;
  uniform mat4 u_ProjMatrix;
  uniform mat4 u_ViewMatrix;
  varying vec4 v_Color;
  void main () {
    gl_Position = u_ProjMatrix * u_ViewMatrix * a_Position;
    v_Color = a_Color;
  }
</script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/fragment-shader">
  precision mediump float;
  varying vec4 v_Color;
  void main () {
    gl_FragColor = v_Color;
  }
</script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

If you want to learn more about lookAt see [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-camera.html)

note: it's perfectly valid to organize matrices like you have and swap columns and rows when using them in WebGL. It's less common though. [The OpenGL specs just call a computer science array row to be column](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-matrix-vs-math.html).